# (Java) Put negative short's bits to an interger

Tags: java, bit-shift

I want to put a short integer (16 bits) into tail of a 32 bits integer (I'm compressing some small-range numbers to an unique integer). But didn't found a better looking way than bellow, I have to use two operation, can it be better?

```
short sh = -1; // 16 bits 1
int zip = 0; // last 16 bits presents a short number

System.out.println("Wrong way, maybe many of us will try first:");
zip |= sh; // expect 0xffff
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(zip)); // but 0xffffffff

System.out.println("Simple way, right but looks ugly, two operations");
zip = 0;
zip |= sh << 16 >>> 16; // expect 0xffff
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(zip)); // yeah

System.out.println("Is there a nicer looking way, one operation for example?");
```

Comment: And what if `zip` is not 0?

Comment: I think it is not possible to do this task using only one operation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All bitwise operations in Java are done using ints or longs, therefore you don't have too much choice here; and casting a shorter primitive type whose sign bit is set will "expand" the sign bit to all "newer created" bits.

There is a solution to do it "in one line", but that will still be two operations:

```
zip |= (sh & 0xffff);
```

Note, it pretty much requires that zip is 0 to start with, or at least that its 16 low bits are 0.